# How to declare component below router outlet without duplicating it?

Tags: angular, angular10

I am learning Angular 10.I have a case where I need to declare my base component in app html under router outlet. I understand  it is happening because app html is encapsulating html, but how to stop it from loading twice ? I can simple put it in router and not declare it in base html and it works, but due to some specific reason I have been asked to achieve it this way.

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-login-component ></app-login-component>
```

My router code:

```
   const routes: Routes = [
    {
      path:'',
      redirectTo:"login", pathMatch: 'full' 
    },
    { 
      path:'dashboard',
      component:DashboardComponent,
      canActivate[LoginGuardGuard]
    },
    {
      path:'login',
      component:LoginComponentComponent
    },
    {
       path:"register",
       component:RegisterComponent
    },
    {
       path:'customer-dashboard-extra',
       component:CustomerDashboardExtraComponent
    }      
   ];
```

So what property can I add or changes do I need to make so that,my logincomponent doesn't load twice, without removing the component from app.html ? when the default page loads, it should be login, but when I click register it should be only register, right now  I am getting register, but also login below that. Thanks :)

Comment: so, do you want this scenario: when you visit /login, the router-outlet will move to login component, but the app-login will disappear? and, in the rest of the routes, the app-login will appear below the current route in router outlet?

Comment: What is the reason you want app-login below your router-outlet?
You could simply place app-login inside a compenent your calling by your router

Comment: @sofa_maniac when the default page loads, it should be login, but when I click register it should be only register, right now  I am getting register, but also login below that.

Comment: @MichelFerreiraRibeiro yes I do understand that and it works as well, but long story short, since I am learning it I have been instructed it to go this way for the app, as they need the base component there for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

As of What I have understood properly, a working demo You can found it here [StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-g5rwxt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Bsically, to disable Login component when you are inside `register` route then you have to pass data to router and you need to get those data from component where you want to read this router data.

**How You can declare data to router ?**

```
{
  path: "register",
  component: RegisterComponent,
  data: { register: true }
}
```

Above, You can see `data` object inside app-routing.module.ts file declared with `{ register : true }`. So all you have to do is read data from app.component when you route to register.

**How You can read data from app.component ?**

To, read data all you need to do is.. first inject Router to constructor.

```
constructor(private router: Router) {}
```

Then, inside `ngOnInit()` lifecylce hook, You have to subscribe to this router object...

```
ngOnInit() {
this.router.events
  .pipe(filter((event: any) => event instanceof NavigationEnd))
  .subscribe(() => {
    var root = this.router.routerState.snapshot.root;
    while (root) {
      if (root.children && root.children.length) {
        root = root.children[0];
      } else if (root.data && root.data["register"]) {
        this.isRegisterComponent = root.data["register"];
        console.log(this.isRegisterComponent);
        return;
      } else {
        return;
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Above code is route from parent to child to find data property of `register` then, we will assign it value to local instance variable. and we hide app-login based on `isRegisterComponent` value is.

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-login *ngIf="!isRegisterComponent"></app-login>
```

So, now you have cleared your doubt. Bu My recommendation is you never mix two component with router, only used either. Thank You.